# Accessing global variable in img.onload function Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onload

I want to validate the width and height of an uploaded image and then returns false if its not valid

I have this

```
  let valido = true;
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  img.onload = function () {
    const width = img.naturalWidth;
    const height = img.naturalHeight;
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    // console.log(width)
    // console.log(height)
    if (width > 588 || height > 204) {
      valido = false;
      console.log('here')
    }
  };
  console.log(valido);
```

On the console it logs 'here' but in the end the value of valido is still true

Comment: Because the 2nd console.log runs before the onload event is executed.

Comment: The last console.log is executed when the script is firstly ran, the "here" console.log is executed when an event is triggered. How do you expect it works?
Btw, the question is not related to Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how the code is executed. The `onload` property indicates a function to be executed when the image loads. This is *after* the code you've written is run, and hence after the latter `console.log`. Even if the image is already available locally as is the case here.

Checkout MDN's [concurrency model and event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for a description of how this all works out in general.